# Meaning of { response in ... } in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to programming and Swift. I was browsing the documentation of [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling) and found this code statement I don't understand to: `responseJSON { response in` in following code block.

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
    print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
    }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
    }
}
```

What does it mean exactly in Swift? I understand it makes request and gets Response which body is returned in JSON but I'm not sure of the meaning of `{ response in`.

Comment: trailing closure used for the last (and only) parameter of `responseJSON` method. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax or https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

Comment: As @Sulthan mentioned, it's a trailing closure.  Closures are one of the more difficult Swift concepts to understand for someone just learning Swift.  I'd advise really nailing down the basics before tackling them.